# How to configure bi-directional sync in SymmetricDS?

Tags: symmetricds

Has anyone achieved a bidirectional configuration with SymmetricDS?

There are many things to configure, and i got most of them:

server.properties:

```
#XXXXXXX nombre de la cabana
#SSSSSSS ip del servidor

engine.name=XXXXXXXXXXX

# The class name for the JDBC Driver
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# The JDBC URL used to connect to the database
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/HutteBullen_XXXXXXXXXXX?    tinyInt1isBit=false
# The user to login as who can create and update tables
db.user=aDDD
# The password for the user to login as
db.password=CC
registration.url=http://SSSSSSS:31415/sync/XXXXXXXXXXX
sync.url=http://SSSSSSS:31415/sync/XXXXXXXXXXX
# Do not change these for running the demo
group.id=server
external.id=000
initial.load.create.first=true
auto.registration = true
auto.reload = true
create.table.without.foreign.keys=true
```

Client is embedded HSQL

client.properties(Generated in the code):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("engine.name", "cabana-" + args[0]);
            props.setProperty("db.driver", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            props.setProperty("db.user", args[1]);
            props.setProperty("db.password", args[2]);
            props.setProperty("registration.url", "http://" + args[4] + ":31415/sync/" + args[5]);
            props.setProperty("group.id", "cabana");
            props.setProperty("external.id", args[0]);
            props.setProperty("job.routing.period.time.ms", "5000");
            props.setProperty("job.push.period.time.ms", "10000");
            props.setProperty("job.pull.period.time.ms", "10000");
            props.setProperty("job.heartbeat.period.time.ms", "15000");

            props.setProperty("intial.load.create.first", "true");
            props.setProperty("create.table.without.foreign.keys", "true");
            props.setProperty("create.table.without.defaults", "true");
```

The Triggers:

```
insert into sym_trigger (trigger_id,source_table_name, channel_id, last_update_time,create_time, sync_on_incoming_batch)
values('TriggerAll', '*', 'transaction', current_timestamp, current_timestamp,1);
insert into sym_trigger_router (trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,last_update_time,create_time)
values('TriggerAll','server_2_cabana', 100, current_timestamp,current_timestamp);
insert into sym_trigger_router (trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,last_update_time,create_time)
values('TriggerAll','cabana_2_server', 200, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

And then, the problem, the sym_conflict(in the server):

```
insert into sym_conflict (conflict_id, target_channel_id, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, detect_type, detect_expression, resolve_type,ping_back, resolve_changes_only, resolve_row_only, create_time, last_update_time)
values ('Conflict-Server-Cabana', 'transaction', 'server', 'cabana', 'USE_TIMESTAMP', 'LASTMODIFIEDUTCDATETIME', 'NEWER_WINS', 'REMAINING_ROWS', 0, 1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
insert into sym_conflict (conflict_id, target_channel_id, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, detect_type, detect_expression, resolve_type,ping_back, resolve_changes_only, resolve_row_only, create_time, last_update_time)
values ('Conflict-Cabana-Server', 'transaction', 'cabana', 'server', 'USE_TIMESTAMP', 'LASTMODIFIEDUTCDATETIME', 'NEWER_WINS', 'REMAINING_ROWS', 0, 1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

The big problem is the next one:
I have many nodes that sync in a star topology. All of them sync in a bi-directional way. All of them have the same schema, and should have the exact same data.

Inserts, and updates work correctly with the configuration above. The problems are the deletes. I am node one, and i create a row, and then it gets synced to the central server, and then to node two. And then node two decides to delete this row, it gets deleted on node two and then on the server, but not on the node that created the row, and i dont know why!. It doesn't stay consistent.

Did anybody achieve full bi-directional replication with SymmetricDS?

Comment: Is there anything in `sym_data` for the row identified with `pk_data` of the table with `table_name` on the central node?

Comment: Hello Johan Dahlin, did you do all the config? I need do this but I don't know how to start. I have some clients (3) with the same database (postgres, 3 schemas with some tables inside) and I have 1 server with the same software (web based PHP). I need make the sync on it and let the DB the same in all of them. Could you give a north, please? Which version of SymmetricDS did you use? Can I use the config shared by you? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set the value for the column `sync_on_incoming_batch` to 1 as explained in the documentation http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/user-guide.html#_bi_directional_synchronization

Comment: I already had set that variable. I edited my answer and added the triggers I created for all tables.

Comment: Are you declaring "on delete" triggers?

Comment: The creation of the triggers for each tables are automatically generated by Symmetric. The after insert, after update and after delete are created by the engine. The SQL commands that a showed are the configuration to set this triggers up. The '*' indicates that this will create all triggers for all tables.